# Find all the links and replace them with their href value

Tags: javascript, regex

I think I have a string like:

```
<a href="site/project/109#" target="_blank">href</a> text, text, <a href="/target" class="test">test</a>
```

And I need to output

```
 site/project/109# text, text, test
```

---

I can find all links

```
var txt = msg.match(/\<a\shref=\"(.*)\"\s(.*)[\<\/a\>]/gmi);
```

And in loop make replace. But I would like to shorten the code, do everything through single **replace**, like this :

```
var txt = msg.replace(/\<a\shref=\"(.*)\"\s(.*)[\<\/a\>]/gmi, $1);
```

But in this case I get: **[object HTMLHeadElement]**

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839)

Comment: why not retrieve elements and their href with `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`?

Comment: From the error message it is also clear that `msg` is not a string.

Comment: Because this is string.

Comment: You are allowed jquery?

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you want the second anchor tag converted?

Comment: In your example, you aren't converting the second anchor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use regex to parse HTML, it's better to generate an element with the content and do the rest on the element.

```js
var str = '<a href="site/project/109#" target="_blank">href</a> text, text, <a href="/target" class="test">test</a>';

// create an element
var temp = document.createElement('div');

// set the content with the string
temp.innerHTML = str;

// get all `a` tags and convert into array
// for older browser use `[].slice.call() 
// for converting into array
Array.from(temp.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(function(ele) {
  // create a text node with the attribute value 
  var text = document.createTextNode(ele.getAttribute('href'));
  // replace a tag wit the text node
  ele.replaceWith(text);
});

// get the updated html content
console.log(temp.innerHTML)
```

Why not regex ? : [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

---

**UPDATE :** The `msg` variable is an element object, a not string that's why it's getting converted to `[object HTMLHeadElement]`(`HTMLHeadElement` refers to the `HEAD` tag, I think something wrong with your core check that also). So do the same as above where replace `temp` with the `msg`. In case you want to keep the original element content then generate `temp` element as above and set content as `temp.innerHTML = msg.innerHTML` .

Comment: I understand, regexp takes my string as html?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery (which is great and does all things) then you can get the href quite easily:

```
var string = '<a href="site/project/109#" target="_blank">href</a> text, text, <a href="/target" class="test">test</a>';
var href = $(string).attr('href');
```

which means that setting the text of the anchor tag is trivial:

```
$(string).text($(string).href));
```